# Are the following implementations of quick sort same?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

I came across these implementations of quick sort on a website , one is a recursive one and another is an iterative one ( using auxiliary stack ) . `Partition` function is same for both of them .

`Recursive quickSort`

```
/* A[] --> Array to be sorted, l  --> Starting index, h  --> Ending index */
void quickSort(int A[], int l, int h)
{
    if (l < h)
    {       
       int p = partition(A, l, h); /* Partitioning index */
       quickSort(A, l, p - 1); 
       quickSort(A, p + 1, h);
    }
}
```

`Iterative quickSort`

```
* A[] --> Array to be sorted, l  --> Starting index, h  --> Ending index */
void quickSortIterative (int arr[], int l, int h)
{
    // Create an auxiliary stack
    int stack[ h - l + 1 ];

    // initialize top of stack
    int top = -1;

    // push initial values of l and h to stack
    stack[ ++top ] = l;
    stack[ ++top ] = h;

    // Keep popping from stack while is not empty
    while ( top >= 0 )
    {
        // Pop h and l
        h = stack[ top-- ];
        l = stack[ top-- ];

        // Set pivot element at its correct position in sorted array
       int p = partition( arr, l, h );

       // If there are elements on left side of pivot, then push left
       // side to stack
       if ( p-1 > l )
       {
           stack[ ++top ] = l;
           stack[ ++top ] = p - 1;
       }  

       // If there are elements on right side of pivot, then push right
       // side to stack
       if ( p+1 < h )
       {
           stack[ ++top ] = p + 1;
           stack[ ++top ] = h;
       }
   }
}
```

What I am thinking is that , these are not exactly 'same' because the first one works on the first part ( from `l` to `p-1` ) recursively and then works on the second part while the other part works on second half ( from `p+1` to `h` ) first and the first part ? 
Am I right in thinking so ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The iterative solution first sorts the second part and then the first.

Comment: Well it didn't matter in this case , but if it would have been some in order traversal print , then the order would create havoc :D !

Comment: Just a minor point: int stack[ h - l + 1 ]; creates a variable length array. This is not allowed at present in C++. Better use a std::stack.

Comment: Note that in most cases, you don't really want to do *either* of these. You want to check which partition is smaller, and recurse into that one first. This limits your worst-case stack depth to O(log N); for the versions you've presented, it's O(N) worst case.